# Internal server error With RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a problem is when change the url of my site, which is generated dynamically.

I have the Apache module mod rewrite localhost wamp server enabled. Before fundionaba perfectly, but before the php url used two variables now to remove one server fails. I do not understand why fails. Can you help me?

It is very strange that server error when you click on these same links that worked previously. If there is a problem with the php variable or php error because it would, but not a server error.

htaccess rules before when it worked perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^nov/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /nov/nov.php?url=$1&url=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /nov/nov\.php\?url=(.+)&url=(.+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^nov/nov\.php$ /nov/%1/%2\.php? [L,R=301]
```

Rules that I used now by removing one variable that WORKS NOT giving the Internal server error:

```
RewriteRule ^nov/([^/]*)\.php$ /nov/nov.php?url=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /nov/nov\.php\?url=(.+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^nov/nov\.php$ /nov/%1\.php? [L,R=301]
```

Let's see if I can say the reason for the error, all I've done is remove one of the variables. Thank you.

Apache Server error log:

```
[Thu Mar 03 10:17:46 2016] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost/
```

Comment: Is your PHP file nov.php causing an error what gives you the server error? Is there something in you PHP-Error log?

Comment: Check your apache error_log for the 500 reason.

Comment: The mistake was in apache is what describes the partner who has the answer. Thank you very much to both, I'll edit my message with the error of apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to exclude the destination you are rewriting to othewise you will get an infinite loop error because **/nov/nov.php?url=$1** also matches the pattern **^nov/(.+).php$**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /nov/nov\.php\?url=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /nov/%1.php? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nov/nov\.php
RewriteRule ^nov/(.+)\.php$ /nov/nov.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: It's amazing, really. It has worked !! I do not understand the other code running and remove only one of the variables was error.

Thank you very much for your help.